# Scanf("%*s") validation in loop. How it exactly works?

Tags: c, validation

I found a strange ,,if number" validation and i can't figure out how it exactly works.

Code:

```
int main(void) {
int stan;
double x, y;
printf("Give two numbers: ");
while ((stan = scanf_s("%d %d",&x,&y)) == 2) {
    if (stan != 2)
        scanf_s("%*s");
    printf("Give two numbers: ");
}
```

How scanf_s("%*s")l works in this program? It is a nice solution in this way or I shouldn't use it?

Comment: That `scanf` call looks unreachable to me. `while (stan == 2) { if (stan != 2) ...` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The `%*s` specifier means, "read *and discard* everything up to the next whitespace character from the input stream."  The `*` in a `scanf` conversion specifier is an *assignment suppression* operator - it means, "don't try to store the thing we just read."

Comment: The first instance of undefined behavior in your code is `printf("Give two numbers: ");` (calling a varags function without a declaration in scope).

Comment: @melpomene, this is obviously just OP sparing us includes; we can deduce from the _s suffixes that OP uses MSVC++, in which it's a hard error to call an undeclared function.

Comment: Melpomene I think that it doesn't really make sense but in one example in my book it was used, so i was really inrested what scanf("%*s") mean.

Comment: Note that the first invocation to `scanf` uses `%d` to scan doubles. This is undefined behavior. If you're lucky, it might work coincidentally for values in the 0..<2^31 range, but that is fickle and unreliable: you probably should make `x` and `y` integers or use the `%Lg` format.

Comment: @zneak thank you very much, i've just started learning C so every clue is important for me.